# FreeBSD: Opening X applications after su to root?

Tags: xorg, freebsd, x11, su, vnc

Using FreeBSD 8.2.  I'm accessing my machine over vnc using tightvnc.  I log in as my normal user.  This is okay.  I can open X applications and they display fine.  Then I su to root and they won't open.  I used to be able to do xhost +localhost but this doesn't work anymore.  I read online about copying .Xauthority, so now in my .cshrc for root I do this:

```
if ($user != "root") then
  setenv XAUTHORITY /home/$user/.Xauthoriy
endif
```

This gets me further but now I get an error:

```
GLib-GIO:ERROR:gdbusconnection.c:2270:initable_init: assertion failed ..
```

I searched for this online and someone said to prefix the command with dbus-launch first:

```
dbus-launch emacs
```

I tried this and it works but it seems kludgy.  How do I get this working so I can launch X based programs after su'ing to root seamlessly (like I could with FreeBSD 6.x)?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I kinda have a fix for this.  There is a nice explanation from this site https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gconf/+bug/336660 :

> The explanation of the problem is the
>   following:
>
> When you su to root from a terminal
>   where you are logged in as another
>   user the new "su-ed" user gonna
>   inherit the environment variables from
>   the parent shell user.
>
> Example: let's say that for the user
>   jack the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
>   environment variable is set to:
>   "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-l5SiTFzmR8,guid=1af28c9d83400a896ef6268d4a7af59f"
>   Now if you open a terminal as jack and
>   make a su to root the
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable
>   shall remain as for the user jack. And
>   here is the problem, exactly this
>   specific env. variable
>   (DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS) generates
>   that problem. Gnome programs like
>   gedit, nautilus . . . use the dbus
>   protocol to communicate with gconf
>   where application specific
>   configurations are stored, and not
>   just. A program executed as root uses
>   a different D-Bus session bus address
>   compared when you execute that program
>   as the jack user for instance. So the
>   problem is that you switch to root,
>   but the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
>   variable still points the the jack's
>   dbus session bus address.
>
> Solution: The root user has a separate
>   dbus session address too (located in
>   /root/.dbus/session-bus/. . .) So to
>   use the root's dbus address when you
>   are in a terminal and "su-ed" to root
>   just clear the
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable.
>   like: export
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" A program
>   that needs dbus communication with
>   gconf for instance, checks that
>   environment variable, and if it is
>   empty it reads the dbus address from
>   the users ~/.dbus/session-bus/
>   directory (the right place). To make
>   this permanent add the following line
>   to the root users .bashrc file: export
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" This means
>   that every time when you su to root
>   and the terminal is not a login shell
>   (the case when you are logged in as
>   jack and opened a terminal and
>   executed su) the
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable is
>   cleared, so the applications gonna
>   read the dbus address from the right
>   place.
>
> by the way you do not need to start a
>   new dbus session with dbus-launch.
>   Even if you do so but the applications
>   still read the dbus address from the
>   wrong place, the problem will persist.

When I unsetenv DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, I can now start emacs in X after su'ing.  However I still get warnings:

```
(emacs 1879): GLib-WARNING **: In call to g_spawn_sync()...
```

Comment: Great! This saved me some time trying to figure out why you can't use "apply-schema" by from a parent root terminal using su. The dbus session address needs to be cleared.

Comment: Nice explanation :)